# Changing pip installation path; OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: macos, command-line, pip, directory

For context, I'm trying to point pip at the directory that PyCharm is using. Running OSX High Sierra. Google hasn't had any answers yet (As far as I can tell).

In the command line, if I enter

```
pip install SpeechRecognition -t /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4/site-packages
```

It gives me

> OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

If I try

```
pip install SpeechRecognition -t /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4/
```

I get

> ERROR: Target path exists but is not a directory, will not continue.

I tried updating pip, and still no luck. What should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target dir you're trying to specify is incorrect - it should be

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

(`lib` dir instead of `bin` that stores the executables).

However, it looks like you are trying to install into the python dist's default site packages dir - you shouldn't need to explicitly specify the target dir in this case. Instead, use the correct `pip` executable:

```
$ pip3.4 install SpeechRecognition
```

If `pip3.4` executable is not available, use the one bundled with Python 3.4:

```
$ python3.4 -m pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Comment: Huh. pip is already pointed at the path you mentioned. PyCharm says that the interpreter is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4. Is that weird? Should I be trying to reconfigure that instead? The lib path isn't one of the Pycham options listed.

Comment: The interpreter is indeed `bin/python3.4`, but it is just the interpreter's executable file and not a directory where the packages are installed - this would be `lib/python3.4/site-packages`. This dir will be automatically resolved from the path to interpreters executable. However, do you experience any troubles with PyCharm after you installed `SpeechRecognition`? If your project in PyCharm uses the same interpreter, it should recognize the newly installed package just fine.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!